# Отправить ссылку в параметре ajax запроса DJANGO

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

как мне отправить запрос, где в параметре находится ссылка ?

Я выбираю данные с таблицы и отправляю их

```
function sendStatusLinkValidation() {
    var grid = document.getElementsByClassName("table")[1];
    var token = '{{csrf_token}}';

    var checkBoxes = grid.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
            let row = checkBoxes[i].parentNode.parentNode;
            var select = document.getElementById("inputGroupSelect01");
            var select_value = select.value;
            var link = row.cells[2].childNodes[0].href;
            $.ajax({
                headers: {"X-CSRFToken": token},
                url: '/send_or_update_violation_links/' + link + '/' + select_value,
                method: 'post',
                success: function (res) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

пошел в сторону urlparse

```
var link = new URL(row.cells[2].childNodes[0].href);
```

но понял, что у меня уже имеется много разных hostname, а если будут еще больше и каждый раз дописывать не очень комильфо)

urls.py

```
path("send_or_update_violation_links/<slug:link>/<str:select_value>", views.send_or_update_violation_links),
```

Я так понимаю мешает в передаче запроса '/' символы, которые находятся в переменной link отправляемым ajax.

Может есть какое-то другое решение ? Спасибо!

Comment: Если я правильно понля, то вам надо экранировать спец символы. Например `/` надо заменить на `%2F`. [Тут](https://www.urlencoder.org/) можете наглядно посмотреть какие символы на что заменяются

Comment: Да, спасибо, я совсем забыл про экранизацию. Но проблема в том, что использую encodeURIComponent. Он действительно экранирует URL правильно, но запрос все равно не отправляется
Но если я уберу из экранированного URl https%3A%2F%2Fozon.ru%2Fproduct%2F - все прекрасно отправится

Comment: К сожалению тут я уже не подскажу) У меня были проблемы с экранированием вот и вспомнил о них)) А вам нельзя отправлять часть ссылки, а потом на бэке дополнять как надо?

Comment: можно конечно, но у меня очень много маркетплейсов, я планировал разобрать с помощью urlparse, но понял, что по-любому есть другое решение, чем такой костыль)

Comment: А почему бы вам не передавать ссылку как тело запроса, а не query параметр? Ну вернее объект, с полем `url` и туда уже как текст пихнуть  и такое же проделать с `select_value`

Comment: было настолько все просто, что просто смешно. slug заменить на path и все прошло отлично
path: соответствует любой строке, которая также может включать символ "/" в отличие от спецификатора str
path("send_or_update_violation_links/<path:link>/<str:select_value>", views.send_or_update_violation_links),

Comment: Можете оставить свой ответ к своему же вопросу, вдруг кто-то ещё столкнётся с такой ошибкой

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы ссылка прошла в запросе, нужно поменять slug на path

**path:** соответствует любой строке, которая также может включать символ "/" в отличие от спецификатора str

path("send_or_update_violation_links/path:link/str:select_value"